# Cannot import name 'SOCKET_OPTION' from 'httpcore.backends.base

Tags: python, httpx

I am trying to make an httpx request from an API, this is my code. I have upgraded httpcore, but still same error. I also uninstalled and installed httpcore but to no avail, it still returns the same response.
I will appreciate it if anyone can help me solve this issue.

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import httpx
import json
import asyncio

load_dotenv()

async def main():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        process_url = "https://api.monsterapi.ai/apis/add-task"

        process_payload = json.dumps({
        "model": "pix2pix",
        "data": {
            "prompt": "Moutain View",
            "negprompt": "",
            "steps": 50,
            "guidance_scale": 12.5,
            "init_image_url": "https://media.gq-magazine.co.uk/photos/63468efef4f48bee2acb7062/16:9/pass/Tom-Holland-Spiderman-what-we-know-so-far.jpg",
            "image_guidance_scale": 1.5
        }
        })
        process_headers = {
        'x-api-key': os.getenv("MONSTER_KEY"),
        'Authorization': os.getenv("MONSTER_TOKEN"),
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

        process_response = await client.request("POST", process_url, headers=process_headers, data=process_payload)

        process_id = process_response.json()["process_id"]

        url = "https://api.monsterapi.ai/apis/task-status"

        payload = json.dumps({
        "process_id": process_id
        })
        headers = {
        'x-api-key': os.getenv("MONSTER_KEY"),
        'Authorization': os.getenv("MONSTER_TOKEN"),
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

        response = await client.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

asyncio.run(main())
```

This is the error I am getting:

> from .base import SOCKET_OPTION, AsyncNetworkBackend, AsyncNetworkStream
> ImportError: cannot import name 'SOCKET_OPTION' from
> 'httpcore.backends.base' (C:\Users\abu aisha\Documents\AI-Whatsapp-Photo-Editor-Chat-Bot\venv\lib\site-packages\httpcore\backends\base.py)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error in HA, and I fixed it by updating the httpcore to 1.17.3.